# How to loop over files in directory and change path and add suffix to filename

Tags: bash, for-loop, filenames, glob

I need to write a script that starts my program with different arguments. I start my program with:

`./MyProgram.exe Data/data1.txt [Logs/data1_Log.txt]`.

Here is the pseudocode for what I want to do:

```
for each filename in /Data do
  for int i = 0, i = 3, i++
    ./MyProgram.exe Data/filename.txt Logs/filename_Log{i}.txt
  end for
end for
```

How can I create the second argument from the first one, so it looks like *dataABCD_Log1.txt* and start my program?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732861/linux-iterate-over-files-in-directory

Comment: @LéaGris The proposed duplicate seems less stellar, especially as one of the answers there still advocates looping over `ls` output. These seem different enough that I have not nominated that as a duplicate of this, either.

Answer (score 1118, accepted):

A couple of notes first: when you use `Data/data1.txt` as an argument, should it really be `/Data/data1.txt` (with a leading slash)? Also, should the outer loop scan only for .txt files, or all files in /Data? Here's an answer, assuming `/Data/data1.txt` and .txt files only:

```
#!/bin/bash
for filename in /Data/*.txt; do
    for ((i=0; i<=3; i++)); do
        ./MyProgram.exe "$filename" "Logs/$(basename "$filename" .txt)_Log$i.txt"
    done
done
```

Notes:

- `/Data/*.txt` expands to the paths of the text files in /Data (*including* the /Data/ part)
- `$( ... )` runs a shell command and inserts its output at that point in the command line
- `basename somepath .txt` outputs the base part of somepath, with .txt removed from the end (e.g. `/Data/file.txt` -> `file`)

If you needed to run MyProgram with `Data/file.txt` instead of `/Data/file.txt`, use `"${filename#/}"` to remove the leading slash. On the other hand, if it's really `Data` not `/Data` you want to scan, just use `for filename in Data/*.txt`.

Comment: `basename -s` does not work. I was able to run the script by changing it to `basename "$filename" .txt`, now it works at intended. P.S. I'm using cygwin so it can be the case.

Comment: Apparently `basename -s` is a nonstandard extension -- I'll edit my answer to use the standard syntax.

Comment: If no files are found/match the wildcard I'm finding the for loops execute block is still entered once with filename = "/Data/*.txt".  How can I avoid this?

Comment: @OliverPearmain Either use `shopt -s nullglob` before the loop (and `shopt -u nullglob` after to avoid problems later on), or add `if [[ ! -e "$filename ]]; then continue; fi` at the beginning of the loop, so it'll skip nonexistent files.

Comment: Perfect `shopt -s nullglob` works great.  Thanks for the info and prompt response.

Comment: This doesn't work when there are files which contain whitespace in their name.

Comment: @Isa It should work with whitespace, as long as all of the double-quotes are in place. Leave any of the double-quotes out, and you'll have problems with whitespace.

Comment: Please note, that it by default does *not* match hidden files. To match hidden files as well, try `/Data/* /Data/.[!.]*`, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/186214/how-to-match-with-hidden-files-inside-a-directory

Comment: Is it possible to replace the path on line 2 (`/Data/*.txt` by a string `$THEPATH` defined somewhere before in the script (`THEPATH="/Data/*.txt"`)?

Comment: @ecjb Yes, but to get the wildcard to expand to a list of filenames, you'd have to leave the variable reference unquoted (`for filename in $THEPATH; do`, rather than `for filename in "$THEPATH"; do`), which can cause trouble if there are spaces in filenames in the path. If possible, it's better to keep the wildcards separate from the variable part so you can quote only the variable part (e.g. `THEPATH="/Data; for filename in "$THEPATH"/*.txt; do`). Other workarounds are possible, depending on the specific situation.

Answer (score 491):

Whenever you iterate over files by globbing, it's good practice to avoid the corner case where the glob does not match (which makes the loop variable expand to the (un-matching) glob pattern string itself).

For example:

```
for filename in Data/*.txt; do
    [ -e "$filename" ] || continue
    # ... rest of the loop body
done
```

Reference: [Bash Pitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#line-57)

Comment: This is still a timely warning.  I thought I had created my script incorrectly, but I had my file extension lower case instead of upper case, it found no files, and returned the glob pattern.  ugh.

Comment: Since the Bash tag is used: that's what [`shopt nullglob`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Shopt-Builtin) is for! (or `shopt failglob` can be used too, depending on the behavior you want).

Comment: Besides, this also checks for files deleted during processing, before the loop reaches them.

Comment: Also handles the case where you have a directory called `dir.txt`

Comment: Don't be sorry; the whole purpose of Stack Overflow is to collect and curate canonical questions rather than have new users reask the same old questions.

Answer (score 109):

```
for file in Data/*.txt
do
    for ((i = 0; i < 3; i++))
    do
        name=${file##*/}
        base=${name%.txt}
        ./MyProgram.exe "$file" Logs/"${base}_Log$i.txt"
    done
done
```

The `name=${file##*/}` substitution ([shell parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)) removes the leading pathname up to the last `/`.

The `base=${name%.txt}` substitution removes the trailing `.txt`.  It's a bit trickier if the extensions can vary.

Comment: Rather than `name=${file##*/}` you can use `name=\`basename $file\``

Comment: @Tk421 — Sorta.  You should use `$(…)` instead of back ticks `\`…\``.  And using `basename` runs a process whereas the `${file##*/}` notation is run by the shell without an external process.  Functionally, the two are equivalent except perhaps in extreme edge cases.  But the shell variable expansion should be more efficient ff, and possibly even measurably more efficient.

Comment: correct substitution:
`base=${file%%$name}`

Answer (score 36):

You can use [find](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_(Unix))'s null-separated output option with *[read](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read_(Unix))* to iterate over directory structures safely.

```
#!/bin/bash
find . -type f -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' file;
  do echo "$file" ;
done
```

So for your case,

```
#!/bin/bash
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f  -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' file; do
  for ((i=0; i<=3; i++)); do
    ./MyProgram.exe "$file" 'Logs/'"`basename "$file"`""$i"'.txt'
  done
done
```

Additionally,

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' file; do
  for ((i=0; i<=3; i++)); do
    ./MyProgram.exe "$file" 'Logs/'"`basename "$file"`""$i"'.txt'
  done
done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f  -print0)
```

will run the *while* loop in the current scope of the script (process) and allows the output of *find* to be used in setting variables, if needed.

Comment: `$'\0'` is a weird way of writing `''`. You're missing `IFS=` and the `-r` switch to `read`: your read statement should be: `IFS= read -rd '' file`.

Comment: I figure some would need search `$'\0'` and spread some stack points around. Going to make the edits you pointed out. What are the ill effects of not having `IFS=` trying `echo -e "ok \nok\0"  | while read -d '' line; do echo -e "$line"; done` there seem not be any. Also -r I see is often default, but could not find an example for what it prevents happening.

Comment: `IFS=` is needed in case a filename ends with a space: try is with `touch 'Prospero '` (note the trailing space). Also you need the `-r` switch in case a file name has a backslash: try it with `touch 'Prospero\n'`.

Comment: Underrated answer. Try the most upvoted ones on a directory containing more than 100k files. Good luck if you're on a low-end machine.

Comment: I see that the answer still have $'\0'. Is that equivalent of ''? I'm not opinionated, I'm just reading the comments and trying to understand if more research is needed and/or if edit is still desired.

Answer (score 14):

Run a command on each file:

Do something (echo) with all *.txt* files,

```bash
for f in *.txt; do echo ${f}; done;
```

Comment: Do you care to read what other said? 1. your answer doesn't have double-quote expansions! 2. what will happen when no .txt files are present?

Answer (score -4):

It looks like you're trying to execute a Windows file (.exe). Surely you ought to be using [PowerShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerShell). Anyway, on a Linux Bash shell a simple one-liner will suffice.

```
[/home/$] for filename in /Data/*.txt; do for i in {0..3}; do ./MyProgam.exe  Data/filenameLogs/$filename_log$i.txt; done done
```

Or in a Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for filename in /Data/*.txt;
   do
     for i in {0..3};
       do ./MyProgam.exe Data/filename.txt Logs/$filename_log$i.txt;
     done
 done
```