# Using all files in a directory with curl?

Tags: bash, shell

This is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

curl -X POST -T /this/is/my/path/system.log https://whatever;
```

As you see, I am using a file called system.log. How can I do that for the complete /this/is/my/path/ path in a loop? There are about 50 files in /this/is/my/path/ which I want to use with curl.

Thanks!

Comment: "How can I do that for the complete /this/is/my/path/ path in a loop?" - I am not sure exactly what you mean.

Comment: Well, I mean, use the curl command on each file in that path.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to iterate over files in directory with bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20796200/how-to-iterate-over-files-in-directory-with-bash)

Comment: @Mat: This has nothing to do with iterating.

Comment: @Mat: That helped me solving my problem, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can upload multiple files using this range syntax in curl:

```
$ curl -u ftpuser:ftppass -T "{file1,file2}" ftp://ftp.testserver.com
```

Answer (score 2):

A very robust solution is to iterate through a for loop. Moreover you can take advantage of this and insert echo commands or delete, or whatever command you want.

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in /this/is/my/path/*
do
    curl -X POST -T "/this/is/my/path/$file" https://whatever;
done; # file
```

Comment: Something like this could be made to work, but `$file` will probably include the whole path (at least on my OS) so you should not need to repeat the path when using the variable... Also, if there are any folders in the path, it is going to get complicated and probably fail.

Comment: Nice solution but $file carries the whole path, no need for the prefix! (bash 5, arch linux)