# Awk to print each file

Tags: linux, awk

I have about 50 files in  a directory

Have

```
File1: 1|2|3

File2: 3|4|5

File3: A|B|C
```

WANT

```
File1: A|1|2|3

File2: A|3|4|5

File3: A|A|B|C
```

I'll appreciate if anyone can solve it with `awk` command. I'm open to other solutions in linux. Also, I want to run it once an perform edits on all files in a directory.

The solution (see below) I have will require me to run it on each file one at a time and I don't think that's efficient

```
awk '{print "A|"$0}' File1
```

Comment: You've already solved it with awk. Now you just need to loop through each file in the directory. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20796200/how-to-iterate-over-files-in-directory-with-bash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below sed command,

```
sed -i 's/^/A|/' file1 file2 file3
```

To make it work on all the files in the current directory,

```
sed -i 's/^/A|/' *
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for `-i inplace`:

```
gawk -i inplace '{print "A|"$0}' file1 file2 file3
```