# Loop through files in Mac terminal

Tags: macos, bash, unix

I am trying to write a simple loop that will loop through the files the current directory and just print the file names.

I tried that:

```
#!/bin/bash    
FILES=/Users/nick/Desktop/*.jpg
    for f in $FILES
    do
        echo $f
    done
```

but it didn't work. Running ./script it just printed "/Users/nick/Desktop/*.jpg". No errors

I am running this on a MacBook Pro 10.10.4

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't work"? Did it print anything? Did you get an error? How did you save the script, how did you run it?

Comment: @choroba I updated the question

Comment: @NikosDim if you see "/Users/nick/Desktop/*.jpg" as output, it's likely because that pattern didn't match anything.  What happens if you just "echo /Users/nick/Desktop/*.jpg" (w/o the quotes)?  This behavior is kind of a 'gotcha' in bash, since $FILES still evaluates to the glob pattern even if no files were actually found.  A common thing to do is add an 'if [ -e $f ]; then ... fi' test around your for loop's body to handle the glob failing to match any files.  Can you confirm if there are any .jpg files in your ~/Desktop?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to iterate over files in directory with bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20796200/how-to-iterate-over-files-in-directory-with-bash)

Comment: Got it working now. Not sure what I was doing wrong. There were definitely jpg files in Desktop. Echo is exploding as expected.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

```
for f in /Users/nick/Desktop/*.jpg; do echo $f; done
```

**Edit**
Actually, I think that [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31797856/loop-through-files-in-mac-terminal#comment51523859_31797856) by @KyleBurton is very clever and should be taken into account since it explains why a result like OP's could be observed.

Comment: I have tried that already but still getting the same behaviour

Comment: make sure you don't have quotes around the path name

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156534/bash-script-error-with-strings-with-paths-that-have-spaces-and-wildcards

Answer (score 4):

Try this, please:

```
for f in $(ls /Users/nick/Desktop/*.jpg); 
do echo $f; 
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Single/one line based solution, (to use/run in Terminal shell):
`find "./" -not -type d -maxdepth 1 -iname "*.jpg" -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' fileName ; do { echo "$fileName"; }; done; unset fileName;`

for your/OP's case, change the `"./"` into `"/Users/nick/Desktop/"`

To use in a script file:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
find "./" -not -type d -maxdepth 1 -iname "*.jpg" -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' fileName ; do {
    echo "$fileName";
    # your other commands/codes, etc
};
done;
unset fileName;
```

or, use (recommended) below codes as script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' fileName ; do {
    echo "$fileName";
    # your other commands/codes, etc
};
done < <(find "./" -not -type d -maxdepth 1 -iname "*.jpg" -print0);
unset fileName;
```

Please checkout my other answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/607424/367237) for description of what code does what function.
As i have shown link to a description, i can avoid repeating same in here.

Answer (score -1):

You can use simple find command to get all things, with type file ..

```
find . type f
```

Comment: The OP did not ask for a way to find files. He wants to simply increment his logic upon the base logic which is looping through the directory. Your answer does not help in anyway.