# Checking for files in a directory with bash script ? what is wrong with this code?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, ffmpeg

I have written this code to check for video files in a directory and convert them with ffmpeg. 
while running this script i get out put as "[ERROR] File Not Found" which i have it in else block.what is wrong with the script that i don't get the files.

```
#!/bin/bash
# set PATH to check existance of video file in this directory
checkfiles='/home/webuser/public_html/shareportal/convertedUp_videos/'
#format of output video file
webm='webm'
for f in checkfiles
do
fullfilename="$f"
filenamewithpath=$(basename "$fullfilename")
filewithoutext="${filename%.*}"
fileextention="${filename##*.}"
changeextension=mv --"$f" "${f%.$fileextention}.$webm"
outputfilename="/home/webuser/public_html/shareportal/converted_videos/$changeextension"
echo "File FUll NAME : $fullfilename"
echo "File name with full path : $filenamewithpath"
echo "File name without extention : $filewithoutext"
echo "File extention : $fileextention"
echo '1 File Converted'
if (ffmpeg -i "$f" "$outputfilename")
then
confullfilename="$outputfilename"
confilenamewithpath=$(basename "$confullfilename")
confilewithoutext="${filename%.*}"
confileextention="${filename##*.}"
echo "File FUll NAME : $confullfilename"
echo "File name with full path : $confilenamewithpath"
echo "File name without extention : $confilewithoutext"
echo "File extention : $confileextention"
echo '1 File Converted'
else
echo "Could Not Convert File"
fi
#get Image of video file on provided time stamp
image_path='/home/webuser/public_html/shareportal/video_images/$filewithoutext.png'
if (ffmpeg -ss 00:00:03 -i "$f" -vframes:v 1 "$image_path")
then
echo "Image Extracted"
else
echo "Could not Extract Image"
fi
done
rm -r f
```

Comment: `if [ -f "$checkfiles" ]` that isn't right. `checkfiles` is a *directory*. `-f` checks for a regular file.

Comment: So what is the difference between a regular file and a file in a directory?

Comment: It doesn't check for files in a directory. `-f` checks whether that exact path is a file or not. A directory is not a regular file. You need to have the check inside a for loop which iterates through a list of files and checks each file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to iterate over files in directory with bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20796200/how-to-iterate-over-files-in-directory-with-bash)

Comment: The duplicate you suggested : the extension of files is .txt which we can set it statically but here the extension varies from one video format to other do  i need to check for extension first?

Comment: Of course you need to apply the answer to your situation. Instead of `*.txt` you can just use `*` to get all the files.

Comment: @kaylum is it right the way i have checked the path for files i have updated the code a bit which i have removed if statement and i directly move to iteration part?

Comment: No it is not correct. The bash `for` loop iterates over the list of items given. It does not know about directories or files. You can't just give a directory to a `for` loop and expect it to loop over the files. That is just not how it works. As the link shows, you need to do `for f in ${checkfiles}*` where `${checkfiles}*` will expand to list all the files in that directory (just like `ls *`)

Comment: @kaylum  Thanks man that worked really well

Answer (score 0):

[How to iterate over files in directory with bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20796200/how-to-iterate-over-files-in-directory-with-bash)

The bash `for` loop iterates over the list of items given. It does not know about directories or files. You can't just give a directory to a `for` loop and expect it to loop over the files. That is just not how it works. As the link shows, you need to do `for f in ${checkfiles}` where `${checkfiles}` will expand to list all the files in that directory (just like `ls *`)
                    – kaylum