# Iterate Over Files in Variable Path (Bash)

Tags: bash, shell, glob

I was looking for the best way to find iterate over files in a variables path and came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20796200/how-to-iterate-over-files-in-a-directory-with-bash) question.

However, this and every other solution I've found uses a literal path rather than a variable, and I believe this is my problem.

```
for file in "${path}/*"
do
     echo "INFO - Checking $file"
     [[ -e "$file" ]] || continue
done
```

Even though there are definitely files in the directory (and if i put one of the literal paths in place of `${path}` I get the expected result), this always only iterates once, and the  value of $file is always the literal value of `${path}/*` without any globbing.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Keep `*` outside quotes: `for file in "$path/"*`

Comment: @anubhava that was it! If you want to post it as an answer I'll gladly accept. Globbing doesn't occur for variables within double quotes I'm guessing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Glob expansion doesn't happen inside quotes (both single and double) in shell.

You should be using this code:

```
for file in "$path"/*; do
     echo "INFO - Checking $file"
     [[ -e $file ]] || continue
done
```

Comment: See [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/239772/bash-iterate-file-list-except-when-empty) for more tips on how to handle an empty directory when iterating with globs.