# Creating files with the same names as the text lines in a file?

Tags: bash

I have file with different text on each line like:

```
blue  
red  
black
blue and red
red and black
```

How to create file for each line of text and the file names to be the same as the text? And also to add extension to the files? The files should look like this:

```
blue.txt  
red.txt  
black.txt
blue and red.txt
red and black.txt
```

Edit: i made a mistake because i have also some lines of text that contain multiple words with space between them. sorry.

Comment: Possible solution you can found in the thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20796200/how-to-iterate-over-files-in-a-directory-with-bash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed` and `xargs`:

```
sed -e 's/$/.txt/' input.txt | xargs -d '\n' touch
```

where

- `sed` substitutes end of the line (`$`) to `.txt` for each line read from `input.txt` file;
- `xargs` builds a list of arguments from the result of the `sed` command and passes it to `touch` command;
- `-d '\n'` option specifies newline character `\n` as a delimiter for the input items.

Comment: This works but adds strange symbol between the extension and the file name: `blue and red.txt`

Comment: @user1800997, could you share the output of `hexdump -C < input.txt` command (preferably, for an `input.txt` file containing only this particular string)? I  suspect the source line contains unusual trailing characters

Comment: I tested this only with one line of text and the sign do not appear, it appears only if there are more then one line. I guess this is a sign for the 'enter' key or line break.

Comment: @user1800997, I guess you have an issue with the clipboard. choroba's answer is correct and should work as well as mine, but you are still getting syntax errors. Could you try to enter the command manually?

Comment: @user1800997 at least the solution works in Bash on Tutorialspoint: http://tpcg.io/vIk5Jr

Comment: For me it's not working this way, but i still could use the command. I just have search and remove this symbol after the files are created.

Comment: The problem was that i was creating the input.txt file on Windows 7, my host os, and then copy it to Debian on virtualbox machine. I had to convert the file to unix format using dos2unix and now the command works without adding symbols in the end.

Answer (score 4):

Read the input file line by line:

```
while read basename ; do
    touch "$basename".txt
done < list_of_names.txt
```

Comment: Are you in bash? If you put everything on one line, you need to insert a semicolon before `done`.

Comment: Yes, i am on bash and code is not on one line. I just created .sh file and copy the code in the file, then if i run the script like this ./script.sh i get the error.

Comment: Weird, it works for me. Try prepending `#! /bin/bash` as the first line of the script.

Answer (score 1):

You could use **GNU Parallel** like this:

```
parallel touch {}.txt < filelist
```

If you want to see what it would do, without actually doing anything, use:

```
parallel --dry-run touch {}.txt < filelist
```