# python, read the filename from directory , use the string in bash script

Tags: python, bash

I am writing a bash script (e.g. `program.sh`) where I am calling a python code in which a list of files are read from a directory.

the python script (`read_files.py`) is as following:

```
import os


def files(path):

    for filename in os.listdir('/home/testfiles'):
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join('/home/testfiles', filename)):
            yield filename

for filename in files("."):

    print (filename)
```

Now I want to keep the string filename and use it in the bash script.

e.g.
`program.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
python read_files.py

$Database_maindir/filename

.
.
.
```

How could I keep the string filename (the names of files in the directory) and write a loop in order to execute commands in bash script for each filename?

Comment: Does the Python code do anything else? It's probably easier to just loop through the filenames in bash directly.

Comment: If that's an option, check out https://stackoverflow.com/q/20796200/354577

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python script in the question doesn't do anything that Bash cannot already do all by itself, and simpler and easier. Use simple native Bash instead:

```sh
shopt -s nullglob
for path in /home/testfiles/*; do
    if [[ -f "$path" ]]; then
        filename=$(basename "$path")
        echo "do something with $filename"
    fi
done
```

If the Python script does something more than what you wrote in the question,
for example it does some complex computation and spits out filenames,
which would be complicated to do in Bash,
then you do have a legitimate use case to keep it.
In that case, you can iterate over the lines in the output like this:

```sh
python read_files.py | while read -r filename; do
    echo "do something with $filename"
done
```

Comment: thank you very much! I followed your suggestion and it worked perfectly!

Comment: however, I notice now that despite the fact that the loop works , when I run the script  it gives an error of unsupported file type (filename) and then it reads the loop correctly.

Comment: @Nat I don't understand how can it work and not work at the same time. From what you pasted I don't see anything where "unsupported file type (filename)" could come from. That must come from somewhere else you didn't share.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this? =

```
for filename in $(python read_files.py); do 
    someCommand $filename
done
```

Comment: `for` isn't a good way to iterate over lines (from a file, command output, or whatever), because it'll get confused if any lines contain whitespace and/or shell wildcards (both of which are perfectly legal in filenames).