# How to execute multiple mv commands from a text file?

Tags: python, bash

I have movers file with multiply mv commands like

```
mv /home/foo/oldTest1/user1.txt /home/foo/newTest1/user1.txt
mv /home/foo/oldTest33/user21.txt /home/foo/newTest33/use21.txt
mv /home/foo/oldTest99/user44.txt /home/foo/newTest99/use44.txt
```

how do I run mv command line by line?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python, read the filename from directory , use the string in bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53787850/python-read-the-filename-from-directory-use-the-string-in-bash-script)

Comment: `bash your_file`?

Comment: @etch_45 , I think my issue is more simple I don't call python script from bash

Comment: @Cyrus , by bash my file name I get mv: cannot move '/home/foo/oldTest1/user1.txt' to '/home/foo/newTest1/user1.txt' : No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

[subrpcoess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html) module can be used to execute bash commands using python. Create a python script run_bash_commands.py as follows :

```
import sys
import subprocess

def main(input_file):
    with open(input_file,'r',encoding='utf-8')as f:
        command = f.read()
        subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1])
```

Assuming commands.txt has the mv commands, pass it as argument to the python script.

```
python run_bash_commands.py commands.txt
```

Comment: I think the issue with mv command it not allowed to enter files so the mv command should look like mv /home/foo/oldTest1 /home/foo/newTest1 (without file)

Comment: any idea how can I remove file name from commands file ? for example every line in commands file the vm command will look like mv /home/foo/oldTest1/user1.txt /home/foo/newTest1/user1.txt  will be replace to /home/foo/oldTest1 /home/foo/newTest1

Comment: In that case you can read the file line by line using `f.read().splitlines()` which gives you a list of lines like `[line1,line1,line3]`. Iterate through this list and append the command you want to execute.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming:

- The filepaths do not contain blank characters.
- The filenames in the directories have ".txt" extension.

Then would you please try:

```
sed -E 's#/[^/[:blank:]]+\.txt##g' movers_file.txt | bash
```

The `sed` command removes filenames from the command lines as you intend
to be passed to `bash`.

Please make sure the `mover file` is fully under your control
not to allow someone else to add an evil code something like: `rm -rf /*`.