# Cannot assign output of sed to a variable

Tags: shell

I refered this 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/251388/prefix-and-suffix-strings-to-each-output-line-from-command
to add prefix to output of `ls`.

I want to store this output of `ls`:

```
file1
file2
file3
```

in to a variable with value:

```
/../file1 /../file2 /../file3
```

This is my `.sh` file:

```
PREFIX="/../"
OUTPUT_INLINE=$(ls | tr "\n" " ")
OUTPUT="${OUTPUT_INLINE}" | sed "s|\<|$PREFIX|g"
echo "${OUTPUT_INLINE}"
echo "${OUTPUT}"
```

Output is:

```
file1 file2 file3
```

It means variable `OUTPUT` contains nothing.

Even if I do:

```
echo "${OUTPUT_INLINE}" | sed "s|\<|$PREFIX|g"
```

I will get:

```
/../file1 /../file2 /../file3
```

What is wrong here ?

Comment: Parse the `ls` output is bad practice

Comment: @G.C. may I ask why ?

Comment: Unix filenames can contain any character, including whitespace or newline. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20796200/how-to-loop-over-files-in-directory-and-change-path-and-add-suffix-to-filename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning OUTPUT variable this command

```
"${OUTPUT_INLINE}" | sed "s|\<|$PREFIX|g"
```

Which means nothing. 
Do as you are already doing with `OUTPUT_INLINE` variable to assign the output of command.

```
OUTPUT=$(echo -n "${OUTPUT_INLINE}" | sed "s|\<|$PREFIX|g")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
OUTPUT="${OUTPUT_INLINE}" | sed "s|\<|$PREFIX|g"
```

That pipes `OUTPUT="${OUTPUT_INLINE}"` into `sed "s|\<|$PREFIX|g"`, which doesn’t do anything. I think you meant:

```
OUTPUT=$(printf '%s' "${OUTPUT_INLINE}" | sed "s|\<|$PREFIX|g")
```

but there’s lots of fragility here around different delimiter types, and you should be able to avoid all that:

```
PREFIX="/../"

for filename in *; do
    printf '%s%s ' "$PREFIX" "$filename"
done
```