# Script to convert sample rate of audio file in Ubuntu

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, audio, sox

```
ls -lrt *wav|wc -l --> 2160
```

Got around 2k audio files with **sample rate 8k**. Need to make an script to convert all the files to **16k Sample rate**.For now Usig **SOX** for converting 1 file at a time.
For eg. :-

```
sox 9560850166.wav -r 16000 -b 16 -c 1 file1.wav
```

*Need an script so that next audio files will be selected from the directory and SOX will be done to change sample rate and it will be saved with a new file name like file1.wav, file2.wav etc...*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to loop over files in directory and change path and add suffix to filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20796200/how-to-loop-over-files-in-directory-and-change-path-and-add-suffix-to-filename)

Comment: yes Sir thank you, reference helped.

Answer (score 3):

Run the below **for loop** from the directory containing wave files

```
a=0;
for i in `ls *.wav`;
do

let a++;
echo "Processing file $i"
sox $i -r 16000 -b 16 -c 1 file$a.wav 

done
```

Comment: Thank you Sir, I already made an script but will keep yours for future use.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need a script for this combination of find and exec will do the job
Use following command

```
find ./ -name "*wav" -exec sox {} -r 16000 -b 16 -c 1 {}.16000.wav \;
```

With this new audio file should get created with .16000.wav appended in original file name.

Comment: oh this sounds very simple, will try it, thank you for your help Sir.

Comment: u are a genius man

Comment: What is the 16 for? If I wanted to convert the file to 44100 Hz, would that 16 become 44?

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
i=0;
for filename in /home/mrityunjoy/myWork/audio_files/*.wav; do
    i=$((i+1));
    sox "$filename" -r 16000 -b 16 -c 1 "file$i.wav"
done
```

*This will give the output in the directory we run the script.*