# How do I search for bash script files without having a specific extension within a folder?

Tags: linux, bash

I want to find bash script files under folders in Array.
But bash script files do not have a specified extension.
I wrote something like this:

```bash
for i in "${array[@]}"
do
    # Here I will write the condition that the file is found in the folder $k
done
```

Comment: Try reading the first line of the files to check if there is ``#!/bin/bash`` or ``#!/usr/bin/bash`` written in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your scripts have `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/bin/sh` in their first line (as they should), then you can use the `file` command to check if a file is a script or not.

For example, take this script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "I am a script!"
```

Output of `file filename.sh` will be `filename.sh: Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable`, which is indicating it is a shell script. Note that the `file` command does not use the extension of the file to indicate its format, but uses the content of it.

If you don't have those lines at the beginning of your file, You can try to run every file (command: `bash filename.ext`) and the check if it was run successfully or not by checking the value of the variable `${?}`. This is not a clean method but it sure can help if you have no other choices.

Comment: I want to use file command but I don't know how to formulate the condition.
Can you write the condition?

Comment: `if [[ -z $(file temp.sh | grep "shell script") ]]; then echo "Not bash!"; else echo "bash"; fi`

Comment: But I don't know the file name. Also I want to know the full name of the file if it is a bash script file. How will this be?

Comment: Here's a link on how to iterate through files in a folder and access their names while doing so: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20796200/how-to-loop-over-files-in-directory-and-change-path-and-add-suffix-to-filename.

Comment: Avoid using the `[[ ... ]]` with subshell when it is unnecessary. This is enough (and simpler): `if file temp.sh | grep -q "shell script"; then ...; else ...; fi`. `grep` indicates in its return code (like most commands) whether it is successful or not.

Answer (score 0):

The file command determines a file type.
e.g

```
#!/bin/bash
arr=(~/*)
for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
    type=`file -b $i | awk '{print $2}'`
    if  [[ $type = shell ]];then
        echo $i is a shell script
    fi
done
```