# Apply sed command to multiple files with similar names with increasing numbering

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have 20 text files named as follows:
samp_100.out, samp_200.out, samp_300.out, ... ,samp_2000.out.
The naming is consistent and the numbering increases by 100 until 2000. I want to make a short script to (1) delete the first line of each script, and (2) apply the following command to each one of the files:
`sed 's/ \+/,/g' ifile.txt > ofile.csv` while keeping the naming the same when changed to a .csv extension

I am assuming I need to use a for loop, but I am not sure how to iterate through the file names.

Comment: You could iterate over the numbers (see ["How do I iterate over a range of numbers defined by variables in Bash?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169511/how-do-i-iterate-over-a-range-of-numbers-defined-by-variables-in-bash), though you'll need to increment by 100 rather than just 1), or iterate over the filenames (["How to loop over files in directory and change path and add suffix to filename"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20796200/how-to-loop-over-files-in-directory-and-change-path-and-add-suffix-to-filename) has examples of how to do things like this).

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed and parallel):

```
parallel "sed '1d;s/ \+/,/g' samp_{}.out > samp_{}.csv" ::: {100..2000..100}
```

Use GNU sed, GNU parallel and braces expansion, to delete first line and replace one or more spaces globally by commas for desired files and make copies.

Alternative:

```
for i in {100..2000..100}
do sed '1d;s/ \+/,/g' samp_${i}.out > samp_${i}.csv
done
```

Comment: Unfortunately I get the error bash: parallel: command not found... I am working through a cluster and I do not think I have authorization to change or add anything to linux! Is there any other way I can achieve this without parallel? Thanks

Comment: @user19619903 see alternative