# Use sed in a for loop

Tags: bash

For all the `.fq` files in the `repaired_reads` directory, I want to convert them to fasta format, where conversion for a single file can be done using:

```
sed -n '1~4s/^@/>/p;2~4p' INFILE.fq > OUTFILE.fasta
```

But when I write a for loop to create all the files, I get an error.

```
for f in `ls -1 ./repaired_reads/*.fq | sed 's/_.fq//'`;
do sed -n '1~4s/^@/>/p;2~4p' $f\.fq > ../fasta/$f\.fasta; # Convert fastq to fasta
done
```

Traceback:

```
bash: ../fasta/./repaired_reads/SRR9200813_1.fq.fasta: No such file or directory
bash: ../fasta/./repaired_reads/SRR9200813_2.fq.fasta: No such file or directory
bash: ../fasta/./repaired_reads/SRR9200814_1.fq.fasta: No such file or directory
```

Comment: [Why not parse ls output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: What's wrong with `for f in ./repaired_reads/*.fq`? You can use bash's built-in parameter expansion operators to remove the `_.fq` suffix.

Comment: Why are you escaping the `.` characters in filenames?

Comment: Do you have a `repaired_reads` subdirectory in `../fasta`?

Comment: If not, you need to remove that from `$f` when creating the output filename.

Comment: Is there really a `_` before `.fq` in the input filenames? Why are you removing that, but not adding it back when you specify the input file to `sed`?

Comment: See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20796200/how-to-loop-over-files-in-directory-and-change-path-and-add-suffix-to-filename/20796617#20796617) for an example of how to do this sort of filename manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the `repaired_reads` directory from `$f` when using it in the output path.

```
for f in repaired_reads/*.fq; do
    f=${f/.fq/} # remove .fq suffix
    outf=${f#*/}.fasta # remove directory prefix
    sed -n '1~4s/^@/>/p;2~4p' "$f.fq" > "../fasta/$outf" # Convert fastq to fasta
done
```

Comment: That also raised an error "sed: can't read repaired_reads/*.fq.fq: No such file or directory
". The files are ".fq" only, not ".fq.fq".

Comment: The sed command in your `for` line removes `_.fq` from the filenames, so I copied that. Should it just be `.fq`?

Comment: Didn't you see my earlier comment asking about that?

Comment: Yes, should be just `.fq`

Comment: I updated my code for that.